# using phong_ramp as a factor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, osl

i found that in OSL there is a shader called phong_ramp that creates a color a ramp depending on the amount of light that a surface gets.

is there a way to use that phong_ramp as a factor output? or as any other thing, because working it as a shader is very clumsy, i would love to do a lot of things with it.

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `phong_ramp` doesn't actually internally calculate that factor; as a BSDF, it's a closure, which is a function to be called by the renderer, later, with more data available. So, while it may appear on the surface that it's internally calculating those colors, it's only setting up the material to provide an environment for their calculation during the actual ray-trace render. (OSL is completely ignorant of lighting.)

So, as much as I hate answering questions with a stout negative, no, you can't determine that factor from OSL. (It literally doesn't even exist yet.) However, if you're looking for a reflectance factor, it's fairly easy to calculate on its own. You do have the surface normal N, the incident ray from the viewer I, and while the light data may not be available you can always substitute in a parameter point, or even hard coded point, representing the anticipated light.

The Blinn-Phong algorithm, for all its brilliance, isn't that complicated to understand and is effectively cited in full on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model). I'm not sure what you're hoping to do with that factor but I wish you luck in doing it and hope this helps! Another thought might be to interpolate eight equidistant points between black and white for the shader, and simply multiply it by a color or other closure color to tune it, but it ultimately depends on what you're aiming for.

Comment: hey sorry for answering this late, hopefully you're still there, but anyways. i've been keeping working on this, and then my question would be, is there a way to get the amount of light that mesh recieves in a point? because I don't care about from where the ray is comming, i think is even worse if i calculate that because i could have a scene with an hdri for example, that can have a million light sources. is that possible to solve with the blinn-phong algorithm? that is wat is visually doing the osl script i put, that's why i wanted that

Comment: what i want to do is a truly holographic material that reacts depending on the amount of light the surface gets, not depending on the angle, like real holographic materials do, like the ones in security seals (those materials also take in consideration the angle of the light, but what i mean is that intensity is what i want as a factor because the angle i can get it with the layer weight node or the fresnel node). thanks!

Comment: Generally, light is only calculated by the renderer post-shader, which is intentional; but that doesn't make it completely impossible. Most of the light data is in Input→Light Path and Input→Camera Data has some related stuff. However, you could attempt a mechanic with a custom property. It's worthy of a new question. (Also, what you're talking about is a reflection hologram; the other kind, a transmission hologram, does exist--I used to make them in an optics lab--but requires a laser and beam splitter to be viewed; great DoF on them though!)